# ajaxStart doesn`t work in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

this code (i mean ajaxStart/ajaxStop) doesn`t work only in Google Chrome.

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",
                url: '<?=base_url();?>' + url,
                async: false,
                success : function(html)
                {
                    modal = html;
                }
            });

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document)
        .ajaxStart(function () {
            $('#spinner').show();
        })
        .ajaxStop(function () {
            $('#spinner').hide();
        });
});
```

how can i use ajaxStart/ajaxStop in chrome?

**UPDATE:** i have no error. google chrome just ignore ajaxStart/ajaxStop action.
html and body instead of document don`t work too.

in backend i use sleep for 5 second to see load process.

yes, i use last version of google chrome.

@Murali, it is magic. browser ignore show(). but, if i write after/before alert(), everything ok. how so?

Comment: I'm not sure but instead of $(document).ajaxStart.... try use $('html,body').ajaxStart... . Maybe it can work.

Comment: Did you by chance update to Chrome 30 recently?

Answer (score 1):

Try moving out of `document.ready` and use [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) , it will get execute even if your request has some error

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(event, xhr, settings) {
        alert('started');
        $('#spinner').show();
    })
    .ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
        alert('completed');
        $('#spinner').hide();
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: @Vitaliy, updated the answer.What error you are getting? try see in console and let us know

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this:

```
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
  $("#spinner").show();
}).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
  $("#spinner").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I´ve had the same problem.
The solution was to use ajaxSuccess.
This is the Global Event approach. You could also use Local Events.
You can read about the difference at [jQuery Ajax Events Page](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)

Differences between ajaxComplete and ajaxSuccess are:
**ajaxSuccess:** This event is only called if the request was successful (no errors from the server, no errors with the data).
**ajaxComplete:** This event is called regardless of if the request was successful, or not. You will always receive a complete callback, even for synchronous requests. It will be triggered every time an Ajax request finishes.

Another issue could be that you should use it outside `$(document).ready(function() {`
Additional issue could be that you have outstanding Ajax requests. See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/)

I´m using jQuery 1.11.1.
Tested in Chrome 42.0.2311.90 m and 42.0.2311.135 m, Firefox 37.0.2

```
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() {
        $('#spinner').show();
    },
    ajaxSuccess: function() {
        $('#spinner').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Having the same Chrome problem - this cured it!